# Mongo. Increase field value regarding data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi there i have some issue but also solution how to do it. But maybe there is solution easier than my.

Issue: Mongodb.
For example I have a structure for `pages` collection:

```
{
  place: 1,
  name: 'One'
  ...
},
{
  place: 2,
  name: 'Two'
  ...
},
{
  place: 3,
  name: 'Three'
  ...
}
```

When i add new item in database it should take palace 4. But if i put to new item place: 1 all old items should shift example:

```
{
  place: 1,
  name: 'NEW ITEM'
  ...
},
{
  place: 2,
  name: 'One'
  ...
},
{
  place: 3,
  name: 'Two'
  ...
},
{
  place: 4,
  name: 'Three'
  ...
}
```

Solution is: I get all item from table by limit with offset, make loop and increase `place` in each item.

Does someone have solution better?

Comment: Insert `place: 0` and then increase all documents by 1

Comment: No) For example for new item i can set `place: 2` and all items that was 2 and more should be 3,4,5......

Comment: Your items is array fields of one document or each item is a document?

Comment: It is one collection with name `pages` that have schema that i provide above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to update all items with greater or equal place in one query before insert the new item. Something like:

```
db.pages.updateMany({place: {$gte: new_place}}, {$inc: {place: 1}})
```

Comment: But do you mean first of all set new item to collection, than get ID, than make `db.pages.updateMany({place: {$gte: 1}, id: {$nin: [ID that i push recently] }}, {$inc: {place: 1}})`. This construction works fine. May i do the same but in one row without insert?

Comment: You can update other items first then insert the new item.